# When WebView got visible it continuously shows [AUX] error. The full error shown as in android 13

Tags: android, webview, android-13

When WebView got visible it continuously shows [AUX] error. The full error shown as

E/GPUAUX: [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:663: Null anb
Can anyone please help me to find the cause of this issue?.

i tried this

step 1:- replace http => https

step2:- implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.2.1'

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

but this is not work for me

Comment: Same error apears when ads are loaded